# Dialog Box not popping up

Tags: powershell

I am working on a script that I got help with a confirmation popup box, the problem is that it's not popping up during the correct conditions (a USB drive with /sources/install3.swm).

The following is my entire code (since the yes condition says do the entire rest of the code).  The code in question that's not popping up is the factory key check:

```cs
# 1. Copy the wim
# 2. Mount the wim
# 3. Inject all the drivers from the driver path recursively
# 4. Commit and unmount the wim

Param(
    # Legacy Path: $DriverPath = "\\desmo\release\ArubaImages\Daily\developer_teamos\master\2.4047.0\Image\Support"
    # Factory Path:
    [string]$DriverPath = "\\desmo\release\ArubaImages\Factory\customer\master\4.4074.0\Support\13.IMAGE"
)

# Check if a USB drive is inserted in the local computer.
do {
    $USB = gwmi win32_diskdrive |
           ?{$_.interfacetype -eq "USB"} |
           %{gwmi -Query "ASSOCIATORS OF {Win32_DiskDrive.DeviceID=`"$($_.DeviceID.Replace('\','\\'))`"} WHERE AssocClass = Win32_DiskDriveToDiskPartition"} |
           %{gwmi -Query "ASSOCIATORS OF {Win32_DiskPartition.DeviceID=`"$($_.DeviceID)`"} WHERE AssocClass = Win32_LogicalDiskToPartition"} |
           %{$_.deviceid}

    if ($USB -eq $null) {
        #Write-Host "There is no USB drive detected, please insert a USB drive"
        #Popup to pause to give user time to enter a USB key
        $Shell = New-Object -ComObject "WScript.Shell"
        $Button = $Shell.Popup("Please insert proper USB key and click OK to continue.", 0, "There is no USB drive detected", 0)
    }
} while ($USB -eq $null)

#Check if more than one USB drive is inserted in local computer.
do {
    if ($USB.Count -gt 1) {
        #Popup to pause to give time to correct USB key
        $Shell = New-Object -ComObject "WScript.Shell"
        $Button = $Shell.Popup("Please insure only the proper key is inserted.", 0, "There is more than one USB drive detected", 0)
    }
    $USB2 = gwmi win32_diskdrive |
            ?{$_.interfacetype -eq "USB"} |
            %{gwmi -Query "ASSOCIATORS OF {Win32_DiskDrive.DeviceID=`"$($_.DeviceID.Replace('\','\\'))`"} WHERE AssocClass = Win32_DiskDriveToDiskPartition"} |
            %{gwmi -Query "ASSOCIATORS OF {Win32_DiskPartition.DeviceID=`"$($_.DeviceID)`"} WHERE AssocClass = Win32_LogicalDiskToPartition"} |
            %{$_.deviceid}
} while ($USB2.Count -gt 1)

#Check if this is the right key
do {
    if (!(Test-Path $USB2\sources\install*.swm)) {
        #Popup to pause to give time to correct USB key
        $Shell = New-Object -ComObject "WScript.Shell"
        $Button = $Shell.Popup("Ooops! You got the wrong key insterted. Please insert the proper key.", 0, "Wrong key insterted", 0)
    }
    $USB3 = gwmi win32_diskdrive |
            ?{$_.interfacetype -eq "USB"} |
            %{gwmi -Query "ASSOCIATORS OF {Win32_DiskDrive.DeviceID=`"$($_.DeviceID.Replace('\','\\'))`"} WHERE AssocClass = Win32_DiskDriveToDiskPartition"} |
            %{gwmi -Query "ASSOCIATORS OF {Win32_DiskPartition.DeviceID=`"$($_.DeviceID)`"} WHERE AssocClass = Win32_LogicalDiskToPartition"} |
            %{$_.deviceid}
} while (!(Test-Path $USB3\sources\install*.swm))

#Quit script if install.wim is not in folder
if (!(Test-Path .\install.wim) ) {
    Write-Warning "install.wim is not in source folder!  Press any key to exit."
    $host.UI.RawUI.ReadKey("NoEcho,IncludeKeyDown")
    Stop-Process -Id $PID #I use stop-process because some reason "exit" isn't working for me.
}

#Factory Key Check
$USB4 = gwmi win32_diskdrive | ?{$_.interfacetype -eq "USB"} | %{gwmi -Query "ASSOCIATORS OF {Win32_DiskDrive.DeviceID=`"$($_.DeviceID.replace('\','\\'))`"} WHERE AssocClass = Win32_DiskDriveToDiskPartition"} |  %{gwmi -Query "ASSOCIATORS OF {Win32_DiskPartition.DeviceID=`"$($_.DeviceID)`"} WHERE AssocClass = Win32_LogicalDiskToPartition"} | %{$_.deviceid}

# You need this to use System.Windows.MessageBox
Add-Type -AssemblyName 'PresentationFramework'

# By default, you're not blasting the USB drive
$continue = 'No'

# If you see the file, prompt the user
if ( $(Test-Path -Path "$USB4\sources\install3.swm") ) {
    $caption = "*** IT APPEARS THIS IS A FACTORY KEY ***"
    $message = "Are you Sure You Want To Proceed:"

    $continue = [System.Windows.MessageBox]::Show($message, $caption, 'YesNo');
}

if ($continue -eq 'Yes') {
    # The user said "yes" to the "do you prompt"

    #Continue on with regular script
    $tempDir = ".\"
    #Write-Host "Temp dir: ", $tempDir
    $copiedWimPath = (Join-Path $tempDir "install.wim")
    #Write-Host "USB key is no longer assumed to be D:, it can be any letter - but having more than one USB key in computer will confuse this script.  The USB key(s) currently attached is/are ($USB)" -ForegroundColor red -BackgroundColor white
    #Write-Host "You may correct any USB key problems (remove/change) until after splitting the image file:",$copiedWimPath -ForegroundColor red -BackgroundColor white
    #Write-Host "Temp dir: ", $tempDir
    $mountDir=(Join-Path "C:\MountOnwardWim" "mount")

    #Create the mount directory
    New-Item -ItemType directory -Path $mountDir -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
    #Mount wim
    Write-Host "Mounting the image to ",$mountDir
    Mount-WindowsImage -Path $mountDir -ImagePath $copiedWimPath -Index 1
    #Inject all the drivers
    Write-Host "Inject the drivers",$mountDir " - This may take awhile, please be patient"
    Add-WindowsDriver -Path $mountDir -Driver $DriverPath -LogLevel WarningsInfo -Recurse
    #Commit and unmount the wim
    Write-Host "Dismounting the image from",$mountDir
    Dismount-WindowsImage -Path $mountDir -Save
    $USB5 = gwmi win32_diskdrive | ?{$_.interfacetype -eq "USB"} | %{gwmi -Query "ASSOCIATORS OF {Win32_DiskDrive.DeviceID=`"$($_.DeviceID.replace('\','\\'))`"} WHERE AssocClass = Win32_DiskDriveToDiskPartition"} |  %{gwmi -Query "ASSOCIATORS OF {Win32_DiskPartition.DeviceID=`"$($_.DeviceID)`"} WHERE AssocClass = Win32_LogicalDiskToPartition"} | %{$_.deviceid}
    $usbDir = "$USB5\sources"
    $splitSwmFilePath = (Join-Path $usbDir "install.swm")
    Write-Host "Removing old SWMs from USB key"
    Remove-Item $USB5\sources\install*.swm
    Write-Host "Splitting the image file: ",$copiedWimPath " - This may take awhile, please be patient"
    Split-WindowsImage -ImagePath $copiedWimPath -SplitImagePath $splitSwmFilePath -FileSize 3072 -CheckIntegrity
    #Write-Host "Moving split image files to USB key - This may take awhile, please be patient"
    #Move-Item -Path C:\OnwardInjecting\install*.swm -Destination $USB4\sources
    Write-Host "Removing install.wim from PC"
    Remove-Item C:\OnwardInjecting\install.wim
    Write-Host "Cleaning up DISM"
    dism /cleanup-wim
    Read-Host "All done! Press any key to exit"
    Stop-Process -Id $PID
} else {
    # The user said "no" to the flash prompt

    Write-Output "Terminating process..."
    Start-Sleep 1
}
```

Comment: Well, that indicates that `$(Test-Path -Path "$USB4\sources\install3.swm")` returns `$false` - we can't really troubleshoot disk availability for you

Comment: what I've done one time when the code was looking for install*.swms that I deleted from the key, I made blank .txt files and renamed it install*.swm …  sure...  it would have broke if I tried to use the .swm, but it was good enough to get me through the code.

Comment: @adam you requested I let you know about this thread.

Comment: Use the same `$USB` variable in all `do{..} while(..)` loops. You are now testing the wrong variables inside the 2nd and 3rd loop. In fact, use ONLY `$USB` everywhere in your code and do not create new variables for that.

Comment: @Theo I appreciate your advice.  However, while you are right, I may be overusing the $USB2,3 etc ..  I am not testing the wrong variables.  In fact, I have this portion of my code well tested and I am testing the right variables in all places.  I can provide an example why one $USB just won't work for me.  The example is the Check if more than one USB drive is inserted in local computer.  When only one $USB is used it does a check to see if a key has been inserted. If I use $USB to the check it loads the previous result (null) not the check to see if there is a key now.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I think you're wrong. Let's take the second do loop for instance. You are testing if `$USB.Count` is greater than 1. Next you get a new variable `$USB2` and rerun the loop. Since variable `$USB` never got updated, performing the same test on `$USB` in meaningless. You repeat the same thing in the third loop: testing `$USB2`, getting a new variable `$USB3` but test for `$USB2` again (which again did not get updated).

Comment: @Theo I'm a big enough man to admit when I'm wrong.  I swear I did test my code and it worked... and didn't work when I tried doing it the way you described.  But... I just did exactly what you suggested and should be no surprise to you, it worked.  An apology is due and I thank you for helping clean up that code. Thank you for your persistence. =)

Comment: The original problem is still persisting, the popup isn't showing when there is a install3.swm... I can't figure out why not.

Comment: I think you need to add `Add-Type -AssemblyName PresentationCore,PresentationFramework` first **OR** use `Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms` and `[System.Windows.Forms.Messagebox]::Show()`

Comment: One more thing. In the loops you are repeatedly creating the $Shell Com Object, but you never destroy it after the PopUp(). This leaves them in memory just using up space. See [here](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/scripting/powertip-release-com-object-in-powershell/) how to clean up.